# add day (Businessday Only)

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to add day considering only business days without loop's like while or for?

It is important the function be flexible to works  no count and not count  the  saturdays.

I'm using this JS function:

```
var novaData = new Date(dataBase.valueOf());
var diasUteisRemanescente;
var isFimDeSemana;
var direcao;


// Remove decimais 
if (diasSoma !== parseInt(diasSoma, 10)) { throw new TypeError('AdicionaDiaUtil utiliza apenas dias uteis.'); }

// Se zero dias, não realiza mudança 
if (diasSoma === 0) { return dataBase; }

//Decide soma ou subtração 
direcao = diasSoma > 0 ? 1 : -1;

//decide numero de iterações
diasUteisRemanescente = Math.abs(diasSoma);

//Intera até chegar zerar os dias 
while (diasUteisRemanescente) {
    // adiciona/subtrai um dia 
    novaData.setDate(novaData.getDate() + direcao);
    //Verifica se o dia é util
    if (isSabadoUtil) {
        isFimDeSemana = novaData.getDay() in { 0: 'Sunday' };
    }
    else {
        isFimDeSemana = novaData.getDay() in { 0: 'Sunday', 6: 'Saturday' };
    }
    //Se for util remove um dia 
    if (!isFimDeSemana) { diasUteisRemanescente--; }
}
return novaData;
```

Comment: Add to a date received as parameter

Comment: Could you clarify what you exactly mean by "add a **business** day"?

Comment: Add days to a date ignoring saturdays and sundays... For exemple, 01/01 (mm/dd) is friday and I add 2 days, it must return 01/05 (thursday)

Comment: @fba_pereira—I think you mean Tuesay 5 Jan.

Comment: There's a momentjs plugin for this: https://github.com/leonardosantos/momentjs-business

Comment: @RobG Yes! Sorry.. jaja

Comment: @SlashmanX I didn't find any function like this...

Comment: @fba_pereira A function like what? The library I posted has a method `moment().businessAdd(7);` which adds 7 business days to the current date (or a date you input)

Comment: @SlashmanX Thks! moment().businessAdd(7); is what i was searching

Answer (score 1):

There are [*many questions here already*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20add%20business%20days) about adding business days, but maybe this isn't an exact duplicate.

There are some rules you need to define, like should adding one day to Saturday be Monday or Tuesday? You seem to like the way moment-business.js does it so the following does the same—adding a day to Sunday or Saturday gives Monday and the passed in Date is modified by the function and returned.

The following moves any weekend date to Sunday for positive or Saturday for negative, then adds "business days" as 7 days for each set of 5. If the start is closer to Saturday (for positive or Sunday for negative) than the number of days to add, (e.g. Thu + 2) then an extra 2 days are added (or subtracted) to get over the weekend.

If the start is Saturday or Sunday, it's moved to Sunday so Saturday plus one day is Monday. If zero days are added, the original date is returned.

Note: I've used the Date constructor to create dates from strings in the test data, but that's only for convenience, it should never be used like that. Always manually parse strings or use a library.

```js
/*  Add business days (Monday to Friday) to a date
**  If number to add is zero, the original date is returned
**  If date is on a weekend, +ve count starts from Sunday, -ve count from Saturday
**
**  e.g. Saturday + 1 => Monday
**       Sunday   + 1 => Monday
**       Friday   + 1 => Monday
**       Saturday - 1 => Friday
**       Sunday   - 1 => Friday
**       Monday   - 1 => Friday
**       Tuesday  - 3 => Thursday
**
**  @param {Date} date - Date to add days to. The original date is modified
**  @param {number} n  - Days to add (+ve to add, -ve to subtract)
**  @returns {Date}    - The original Date with days added or subtracted
*/
function addBusinessDays(date, n) {

  // If adding zero days, just return date
  if (n == 0) return date;
  
  // Setup
  var weeks   = Math[n>0? 'floor' : 'ceil'](n / 5);
  var remDays = n % 5;
  var dayNum = date.getDay();
  var daysToAdd;
  
  // Move date to Sun (+ve) or Sat (-ve) if start is on a weekend
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + (n > 0? (dayNum == 6? 1 : 0 ) : (dayNum == 0? -1 : 0)));

  // Reset dayNum in case it just moved
  dayNum = date.getDay();

  // Calculate days to add - deal with +ve and -ve and if days to add is bigger than distance
  // to a weekend
  var daysToAdd =  weeks*7 + (n > 0?(remDays > (5 - dayNum)? 2 : 0) : (-1*remDays >= dayNum? -2 : 0)) + remDays;
  
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToAdd);
  return date;
}

['2016-01-01 1', // Fri 1 Jan
 '2016-01-01 2', // Fri 1 Jan
 '2016-01-02 2', // Sat 2 Jan
 '2016-01-05 1', // Tue 5 Jan
 '2016-01-05 4', // Tue 5 Jan
 '2016-01-05 14', // Tue 5 Jan
 '2016-01-02 1', // Sat 2 Jan
 '2016-01-03 1'  // Sun 3 Jan
 ].forEach(function(v){
  var b = v.split(' ');
  document.write(f(new Date(b[0])) + ' ' + b[1] + ' : ' + f(addBusinessDays(new Date(b[0]), b[1])) + '<br>');
});

document.write('<br>Negatives<br><br>');

['2016-01-04 -1',  // Mon 4 Jan
 '2016-01-04 -2',  // Mon 4 Jan
 '2016-01-02 -2',  // Sat 2 Jan
 '2016-01-05 -1',  // Tue 5 Jan
 '2016-01-05 -4',  // Tue 5 Jan
 '2016-01-05 -14', // Tue 5 Jan
 '2016-01-02 -1',  // Sat 2 Jan
 '2016-01-03 -1'   // Sun 3 Jan
 ].forEach(function(v){
  var b = v.split(' ');
  document.write(f(new Date(b[0])) + ' ' + b[1] + ' : ' + f(addBusinessDays(new Date(b[0]), b[1])) + '<br>');
});

function f(d) {
  var days = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split(' ');
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0'+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0'+d.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +days[d.getDay()];
}
```