# Javascript Date Blocker

Tags: javascript, date

What can I add into the following script so that it doesn't land on dates that i specify?

For example, in 5 days time it's 25/12/17, but i want to black list this (and other) dates.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```js
function addDates(startDate,noOfDaysToAdd){
  var count = 0;
  while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
       //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
       count++;
    }
  }
  return startDate;
}

function convertDate(d) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}


var today = new Date();
var daysToAdd = 6;
var endDate = addDates(today,daysToAdd);
document.write(convertDate(endDate));
```

Comment: you want to blacklist specific dates, or patterns like every Tuesday, and what do you want the date to be if blacklisted - go to the next day?

Comment: If I understand, you mean that if, for example, you want 1 day next, and tomorrow is in the blacklist it will return the day after tomorrow?

Comment: I guess you should compare the adjusted date to see if it's a "black" day, then keep adding 1 day until it's not a black day or weekend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How do I add business days in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297323/how-do-i-add-business-days-in-javascript) and [*add day (Businessday Only)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198187/add-day-businessday-only). There are probably others too.